# Variable Length Array

Tags: c, c99

I would like to know how a variable length array is managed (what extra variables or data structures are kept on the stack in order to have variable length arrays).

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a dynamically sized array (implementation-dependent, but most commonly on the stack). It's pretty much like `alloca` in the old days, with the exception that `sizeof` will return the actual size of the array, which implies that the size of the array must also be stored somewhere (implementation-dependent as well, but probably on the stack too).

Comment: That's not entirely true, because there was no way to interrogate the size of an `alloca()` array after it had been created, but `sizeof` works on VLAs (so if you do call `sizeof` on the array, that size must be kept somewhere).

Comment: @caf: good point - I guess the size also needs to be stored somewhere (implementation-dependent) then - I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The size of variable length arrays is determined on run-time, instead of compilation time.
The way it's managed depends on the compiler.
GCC, for instance, allocates memory on the stack.
But there is no special structure. It's just a normal array, whose size is known at run-time.

Answer (score -2):

alternatively you could use some containers, e.g. ArrayList in java or vector in c/c++

Comment: -1 not anything to do with the question (how is a feature of C99 might be implemented) .